# Creating PDF with checkbox selection with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, checkbox

I`m trying to fill some PDF forms in a template. The filling works perfectly but when i select multiple PDF to fill and output with the help of checkbox, it usually outputs template 3 filled. How can i select with checkbox which PDF to fill and export. The data is the same on all the PDF template.

Actual result: checkbox 1,3,4 checked, pdf resulted in template 1 and 3, only 3 being filled with data.

Expected result: after submitting with checkbox 1,3,4 checked, PDF resulted 1,3,4 filled with data.

**index.php**

```
<form action="print.php" method="post">
<input name="a[name]" placeholder="name" style="text-transform:uppercase" type="text" width="100px;">
<input name="a[city]" placeholder="city" style="text-transform:uppercase" type="text" width="100px;">
<input name="a[address]" placeholder="address" style="text-transform:uppercase" type="text" width="100px;">
<input name="a[phone]" placeholder="phone" style="text-transform:uppercase" type="text" width="100px;">
<input name="a[phone2]" placeholder="phone" style="text-transform:uppercase" type="text" width="100px;">
<br/><br/>

<input type='checkbox' id='t1' name='t1'>Template 1 <br/>
<input type='checkbox' id='t2' name='t2'>Template 2 <br/>
<input type='checkbox' id='t3' name='t3'>Template 3 <br/>
<input type='checkbox' id='t4' name='t4'>Template 4 <br/>
<input type='checkbox' id='t5' name='t5'>Template 5 <br/>

  <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p> 
</form>
```

**print.php**

```
<?php
    require('fpdm.php');
    $fields = $_POST['a'];

    $t1=NULL;$t2=NULL;$t3=NULL;$t4=NULL;$t5=NULL;
    if(isset($_POST['t1']))
    $t1 = $_POST['t1'];
    if(isset($_POST['t2']))
    $t2 = $_POST['t2'];
    if(isset($_POST['t3']))
    $t3 = $_POST['t3'];
    if(isset($_POST['t4']))
    $t4 = $_POST['t4'];
    if(isset($_POST['t5']))
    $t5 = $_POST['t5'];

    if($t1!=NULL){ 
        $pdf = new FPDM('template1.pdf');
        $pdf->Load($fields, false); 
    }

    if($t2!=NULL){ 
        $pdf = new FPDM('template2.pdf');
        $pdf->Load($fields, false);
    }

    if($t3!=NULL){ 
        $pdf = new FPDM('template3.pdf');
        $pdf->Load($fields, false); 
    }

    if($t4!=NULL){ 
        $pdf = new FPDM('template4.pdf');
        $pdf->Load($fields, false);
    }

    if($t5!=NULL){ 
        $pdf = new FPDM('template5.pdf');
        $pdf->Load($fields, false); // second parameter: false if field values are in ISO-8859-1, true if UTF-8
    }
    $pdf->Merge();
    $pdf->Output();
    ?>
```

Comment: you keep overwriting `$pdf` with a NEW pdf for every checkbox selected, so there's nothing to merge - you'll only ever have one pdf page, for whatever checkbox was processed last.

Comment: And how do make it not overwrite? Can i save every PDF created in a archive and initiate a download of every PDF. Or how do I do it so that every PDF created is merged and displayed in the browser.